# React, dynamic ANTD tabs and router

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, tabs, router

I'm new to reactJS, get confused when trying to create dynamic (antd) tab.

Basically, i have two layers in Application, the first one is Sidemenu Bar, located on left of the screen, and the second layer is content pages, which represented with Tabs.
The Sidemenu has some variable numbers of menu buttons (modules). When each button are pressed, then React will render that module (each module represent by individual JSfile) to the content layer, inside a new Tab panel. The module page itself, can be duplicated on the Tab.

To do that I created a sidemenu.js which contain a menu buttons (and its corresponding URL), and appPages.js to hold that Tabs that will render the specific module(s).

How to make it possible ? where I should write the routes (react-router-dom) ?
I search for this topic, and found it solved using the same js file, not the separated file or component.

Please check my sandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamictabs-83mop

Thank you. Really appreciated for any help, and so sorry about my english.

Comment: Your `Tab` container is handling the "routing" to content based on the active tab, it isn't clear what app navigation/routing could do for you here. Are you basically wanting the sidebar to also control the active tab? Or are you wanting to link out to other pages within your app?

Comment: No, not from outside the app. And yes, the sidebar should be able to create a new tabs (with spesific page from my app), its supposed change the index of the tabs too.

Comment: Tried using the sidebar to set the `activeKey` prop of the `Tabs` container? [API](https://ant.design/components/tabs/#API)